# Getting control back to main program in java while using thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm invoking thread.In that thread there is `while(true)` condition because of that I'm not able to execute next thread.

Snippet is here

```
ASubscriber aSubscriber=new ASubscriber();      
        aSubscriber.run();
        System.out.println("Starting Subscriber Thread");
BSubscriber bSubscriber=new BSubscriber();
        bSubscriber.run();
```

In each of `run` method of ASubscriber and Bsubscriber has below Code :

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
        while (true) 
     {
        //I'm going some task     
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aSubscriber.run();
System.out.println("Starting Subscriber Thread");
```

`Thread#run` does not start threads.

It just runs them on the current thread.

You probably want

```
aSubscriber.start();
```